# How to create dropdown box?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, drop-down-menu

In my app I want to provide option in dropdown box, I know there is no such thing in iPhone can I create dropdown box using available controllers? Please can anyone suggest me how I can achieve this?

Comment: yes, i implemented UIPicker to get drop-down box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deepak, You can create a Drop down like control with a help of a UIButton and a UITableView indicating the drop down list. But for sure your application would be rejected by Apple.

Most of the iPhone users would be comfortable using a drop down box in an iPhone app, because people got used to Pickers .

So better go for using UIPicker, which is meant for what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks Krishnan, I used Picker view to get drop-down list

Comment: @Sunil Kumar Sahoo Can you provide a sample code so it may help others?