# help needed for combo box in iphone

Tags: iphone, combobox, textfield

Please help me to create drop down box using iphone. I tried in pickerview with textfield but not worked as my requirement can u suggest the url for to solve this problem. The data should come from xml and as a select option in html.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988097/how-to-create-dropdown-box

Comment: Pretty much the exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988097/how-to-create-dropdown-box

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a UITableView with the options, which upon selecting a cell, returns the value of that cell to whatever control that has the select.

For the select you can use a button with a custom image for example, and show a table using presentModelViewController.

When the TableView shows and a selection is made, you store the selected value and dismiss the tableView using dismissModalViewController.

I had the same problem where the Picker just did not fit my requirements and used the tableView solution.

Comment: Nice thinking. I'd like to add that clicking the item to make the menu drop down, probably won't be so smooth as people are used to. Still +1 for the thinking.

Comment: @Joetjah, maybe you can play around with the positioning and the animation, you should be able to make it work pretty closely like a dropdown. Although you also stray further from the apple GUI design guidelines.