# Drop down list for iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, interface-builder, drop-down-menu

How can I add drop-down list to my iPhone application via Interface builder in Xcode 4. I can't see any object like drop-down list controller or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive the control you might want is the UIPicker ([Here's an image, its at the bottom](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/newtutorials/iphone/UIPickerView/UIPickerView.gif)). This is the control that pops up when you select a dropdown list in safari on iOS. You can select it in the object picker in the interface editing area. There is no dropdown list controller as such, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UIPickerView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html), but it sounds like your more likely after [`UIActionSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006801) which will show a number of buttons to choose from. If these don't meet your needs you can always roll your own custom views, but this is more work. Apple's provided UI components are a good start.

Note: there's no Interface builder way to create a UIActionSheet, you have to do it in code, but it's pretty straight foward (see RootViewController class files in this Apple [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079) project).

Answer (score 0):

create a button (like dropdown button) and when you click on that button call another viewcontroller which you want to display and add it as subview to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Gayan, I think your question is already answered. please check this [How to create dropdown box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988097/how-to-create-dropdown-box/5988176#5988176)

And as TOm H and petert mentioned , I too believe that you need to use UIPickerView.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way of doing it http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/a-simple-drop-down-list-for-iphone/

Or here is one not everyone knows: The action sheet is basically a drop down list if you think about it. And if you keep adding buttons to a UIActionSheet it ends up turning into a table. So just have your button call a UIActionSheet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN8BM.png