# How to add Drop Down list?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to create one drop down list contains some Languages. By selecting any language
 of this list, it should list out corresponding language details, for example, if I select English, then it will list English songs. All details are coming from a url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create dropdown box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988097/how-to-create-dropdown-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need Accordion view, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944428/how-to-implement-an-accordion-view-for-an-iphone-sdk-app) question and also [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) sample will give the right idea.

Comment: Yes, But now how I implement this drop down code into my project ?

Comment: write your mail id i shell send you a sample. you will just import TableVC class and use it in your navigation controller(of project)

Answer (score 0):

You can use apop-over for this. In the pop-over, create a tableview to display various options.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UIPickerView` for the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

The action sheet is basically a drop down list if you think about it. And if you keep adding buttons to a UIActionSheet it ends up turning into a table. So just have your button call a UIActionSheet.

Try adding 7  or more buttons to the UIActionSheet and watch it turn into a list.  Its convenient.

[image]